# Using Outer with Compiled functions that accept more than 2 arguments

Tags: programming

How does one use `Outer` with a compiled function that accepts 3 or more arguments. Alternatively, how does one create a compiled function with 3 or more arguments that can be used with `Outer`?

I am trying to use the following function:

```
minimumImagePD =  Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}, {z, _Real}}, 
                 Total[( (x - y) - z * Round [ (x - y) / z]) ^ 2]]
```

This function compiles just fine but you can't use it with `Outer`. Trying the following doesn't work because `Compile` does not "see" the argument 'z':

```
minimumImagePD2[z_Real] =  Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}}, 
                 Total[((x - y) - z * Round[ (x - y)/z] ) ^ 2]]

    Outer[minimumImagePD2[3.2], {{2.1, 3.2, 4.3}}, {{3.2, 4.3, 2.8}, 
                           {1.1, 2.2, 3.3},   {3.4, 2.0, 6.5}}, 1].
```

Now, If I replace `z` in `minimumImagePD` with a number as follows:

```
minimumImagePD3 =  Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}}, 
  Total[((x - y) - 3.25026*Round[(x - y)/3.25026])^2]]
```

The function compiles and works fine as with the following example:

```
Outer[minimumImagePD3, {{2.3, 4.3, 6.5}}, {{2.1, 4.8, 7.3}, {2.2, 
   1.1, 4.3}, {2.1, 3.3, 4.7}}, 1] // Flatten
```

Which gives:

```
{0.93, 1.11557, 3.14325}
```

As noted by Oleksandr R. below, using set-delayed in `minimumImagePD2` solves the problem.

Comment: The problem is not the number of arguments. It is that Total doesn't accept a sequence as argument. The solution : `minimumImagePD = 
 Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}, {z, _Real}}, 
  Total[List @ ((x - y) - z*Round[(x - y)/z])^2]]`

Comment: @andre, actually the result of the calculation is NOT a sequence it's a list, as both x and y are Lists (Hence the 1 in {x, _Real, 1} etc. The function works fine If I replace z with a number instead. So the problem is with `Outer` as there's no room for that third argument.

Comment: must go outside. I See that in 2 hours. Sorry

Comment: @RunnyKine: Could you give an example call to Outer with the minimumImagePD?

Comment: @Joel Klein, that's exactly the reason I asked this question. There's no place for the third argument `z` to go. That's why I tried the 2nd variation of the function. `minimumImagePD` should accept `List` just like I showed with `minimumImagePD2`.

Comment: @Oleksandr R, x and y are Lists of Lists. See my edit. The question still holds. Set delayed does not compile the function, and defeats the purpose of using a compiled function.

Comment: @OleksandrR., you're right it works. Thanks.

Comment: @OleksandrR. It looks like using Set delayed also defeats my purpose of compiling the function as it is an order of magnitude slower than the case where I included `z` as a number directly. Of course I can always hardcode `z` directly but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7428/discussion-between-oleksandr-r-and-runnykine)

Comment: @RunnyKine Yet I have understood the question, I wonder if you are aware that Outer accept more than 2 lists : Outer[f,list1,list2,list3...] is OK, so that list3 can be {z}

Comment: @RunnyKine, perhaps I've misunderstood the problem, but why not use `Outer[minimumImagePD[##, zvalue] &, xlist, ylist, 1]`

Comment: @Simon Woods, that's brilliant and elegant. Thanks. Why don't you post that as an answer. Also it looks like Andre was thinking along the same line as my answer below. But I prefer yours better than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original definition of `minimumImagePD` can be used with `Outer` with this syntax:

```
Outer[minimumImagePD[##, zvalue] &, xlist, ylist, 1]
```

`Outer` provides two arguments to the pure function `minimumImagePD[##, zvalue] &`, and the pure function inserts those two arguments into the `##` ([`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html)), so that `minimumImagePD` is called with the expected three arguments in total.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. So elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand 100% what you are looking for but does this help:

This inserts the value into the compiled function:

```
minimumImagePD2[zIn_Real] := 
  With[{z = zIn},
   Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}}, 
    Total[((x - y) - z*Round[(x - y)/z])^2]]]

f = minimumImagePD2[3.25026]
```

The use as before.

```
Outer[f, {{2.3, 4.3, 6.5}}, {{2.1, 4.8, 7.3}, {2.2, 1.1, 4.3}, {2.1, 3.3, 4.7}}, 1]
(* {{0.93, 1.11557, 3.14325}} *)
```

As suggested by OleksandrR, the `With` is not strictly necessary, so you can also go with

```
minimumImagePD2[z_Real] := 
   Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}}, 
    Total[((x - y) - z*Round[(x - y)/z])^2]]]
```

I find the `With` solution clearer, but clearly that is a matter of taste.

Comment: this has been suggested above by Oleksandr R. It's just adding set-delayed to my `minimumImagePD2` function.

Comment: I am doing something somewhat different here; I generate the compiled function with the proper value inside and then use it as often as I want. Also this presetting allows for optimizations in compile

Comment: @OleksandrR., I'd leave it in; it's more general for other type of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more elegant way, I think, to solve this problem. By including the third argument as one of the Lists in `Outer`.

```
minimumImagePD = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {y, _Real, 1}, {z, _Real}}, 
  Total[((x - y) - z * Round[ (x - y) / z] )^2]]
```

And using it like this:

```
Outer[minimumImagePD, {{2.3, 4.3, 6.5}}, {{2.1, 4.8, 7.3}, {2.3, 1.1, 
    4.3}, {2.1, 3.3, 4.7}}, {3.25026}, 1] // Flatten
```

Comment: This is also how I would do it. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks.